# Event Log(Event log created event)

Tags: c#, events

I would like to know if how can we catch the event in **C#** when a **system event log** is created. Also I would like to know if how can I get **only ERROR LOGS from Windows event logs** using **C#**.
I have the following code but it just returns me all logs. I just need ERROR logs:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application", Environment.MachineName);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in eventLog1.Entries)
            {
                Label1.Text += "Log is : " + entry.Message + Environment.NewLine;

            }
```

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN page -> [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CreateEventSource` static method of `EventLog` class to create event log like

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyApp","Application");
```

`EventLog` class present in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

You can use `WriteEntry()` method to write to the event log. `EventLogEntryType` enum can be used to specify the type of event you want to log. An example below

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent, EventLogEntryType.Warning,  234);
```

See [How to write to an event log by using Visual C#](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/307024)

if you are looking for reading only `ERROR` level log then you can use the below code block. You just need to check `EntryType` of the eventlog entry and then print/display accordingly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog el = new EventLog("Application", "MY-PC");
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in el.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```